# Program received signal: “0”. warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

Tags: objective-c

**Require urgent help!:(**

i m developing a game and i m dealing with around 20 images at the same time.
As per my knowledge, i m allocating and deallocating the images at right places.
Game runs for around 15 min fine but quits with an error message:

**"Program received signal: “0”. warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame"**

i also tried debugging with memory leak tools provided in Xcode but could not find any issue with memory management or any increase in memory size 
**on simulator it works fine but not on the device.**

i m confused wht can be the issue.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If gdb cannot restore the current frame, your stack is probably broken. This can result from huge stack allocations, e.g. a huge array/struct in a local variable.

If you don't find the problem, try enabling message logging ([described here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECOBJECTIVEC)). Then you'll find the last valid method call at least.